# Add a dark and white margins around non-rectangular object - by using filters?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, filter, selection, margin

Is there a *programmatical* way in ActionScript (maybe by using [display filters](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7dba.html)) to add the white and then dark borders around objects like at the following picture? Or has the border been added to the graphical assets already by Photoshop or similar tool?

[image]

The image above is a screenshot of the game Magic Land (c) Wooga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use two GlowFilters to achieve this:

```
displayObject.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xffffff, 1, 4, 4, 10, 2), 
                         new GlowFilter(0x0, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 10, 2)];
```

You might want to experiment with the values a bit.

- The thickness is mainly controlled by the blur values (4 for the white and 1.5 for the black in the example above).
- Since we don't really want a blurry look we need to use a high strength (10 in the example above).
- When using a high strength, it is usually best to set quality to 2 from the default 1, otherwise the strokes will look a bit pixelated. In that case you need to reduce the strength a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I will test this. Yes, bluriness was confusing me.

Comment: The glow filter is definitely the right answer. I didn't realize Flash allows the strength to be far beyond 100%. At 25500%, the glow becomes a solid color. I've deleted my solution.